# GridBagLayout centering components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have been trying for a while to make this work. 
I have looked at many tutorials and examples on-line, nothing seems to help.

The combo box and the label are both centered right under each other in the middle of the frame.

I know that there needs to be a `GridBagConstraints` and you need to set the gbc every time you add a new component.

I am doing that so I am not sure why it's not working.

Also why would it be in the center?
Shouldn't it be in the top left if anything?

```
public class Application {
ArrayList listOfTickers = new ArrayList();
JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;
JLabel jLabel;
GridBagLayout layout;
GridBagConstraints gbc;
JComboBox comboBox;


Application(ArrayList listOfTickers) throws BadLocationException {
    this.listOfTickers = listOfTickers;

    setLabels();
    setComboBox(listOfTickers);
    setFrameAndPanel();
    addComponents();
    closeFrame();
}

private void addComponents() {
    addobjects(jLabel, panel, layout, gbc, 1, 3, 4, 2);
    addobjects(comboBox, panel, layout, gbc, 3, 0, 2, 1);
}

private void setLabels() {
    jLabel = new JLabel("test");
}

private void closeFrame() {
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void setComboBox(ArrayList listOfTickers) throws BadLocationException {
    comboBox = new JComboBox(listOfTickers.toArray());
    comboBox.addActionListener(e -> {
        String ticker = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    });
}

private void setFrameAndPanel() {
    frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
    panel = new JPanel();
    layout = new GridBagLayout();
    panel.setLayout(layout);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
}

public void addobjects(Component component, Container panel, GridBagLayout layout, GridBagConstraints gbc, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight) {

    gbc.gridx = gridx;
    gbc.gridy = gridy;

    gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
    gbc.gridheight = gridheight;

    layout.setConstraints(component, gbc);
    panel.add(component, gbc);
    } 
}
```

Comment: *"Also why would it be in the center? Shouldnt it be in the top left if anything?"* - No, this is how `GridBagLayout` works (and, yes, it can time to get your head around)

Comment: Personally, I would avoid `addobjects` style coding, as it greatly restricts what you can do or requires you to write methods for every possible parameter combination

Comment: You'll also find that `gridWidth` and `gridHeight` can mess with the layout if you're not using it properly

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also why would it be in the center? Shouldnt it be in the top left if anything?

No, this is how GridBagLayout works, `GridBagLayout` will layout it's components around the centre of the `container`.  You can play around with the `weightx/y` properties to change how much of the remaining space is allocated to a given cell.

I would also recommend avoid `gridwidth` and `gridheight` until you have a better understanding of what these do, as they are effecting the position of your components

The following will move the components to the top/left point of the container...

[image: Top/Left]

```
private void addComponents() {
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    panel.add(jLabel, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 0;

    panel.add(comboBox, gbc);
}
```

Although, since you're applying a `GridBagLayout` to the `JFrame` itself, I'd be tempted to change the `weightx/y` and `anchor` properties for the `panel` itself when you add it to the frame, it will make it much simpler

> so if I wanted to let say build a calculator with positioning the buttons in specific areas, essentially transforming the entire panel into one big grid and plotting my containers inside that grid what would be the best layout to use and how would I do that?

That depends ultimately on what you want the UI to look like.  If all you want is for all the buttons to evenly occupy the available space, the maybe `GridLayout` would be a better choice...

[image: GridLayout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application();
    }

    public Application() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
            String labels[] = new String[] {"7", "8", "9", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "", "0", ""};
            for (String label : labels) {
                if (label.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    add(new JLabel());
                } else {
                    add(new JButton(label));
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Note, I had to allow for two empty spaces around the <kbd>0</kbd> button, this is a requirement of `GridLayout`, as you don't get control over which cells the components actually appear, they are simply laid out in a linear fashion.

However, if you would prefer something that looks more like most calculators, then you'll need `GridBagLayout`...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application();
    }

    public Application() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            String labels[][] = new String[][]{{"7", "8", "9"}, {"4", "5", "6"}, {"1", "2", "3"}};
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            for (String[] row : labels) {
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                for (String col : row) {
                    add(new JButton(col), gbc);
                    gbc.gridx++;
                }
                gbc.gridy++;
            }
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = 3;
            add(new JButton("0"), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Needs drive musts, you need to decide on the need of flexibility over uniformity (in this case).  `GridBagLayout` is very powerful and flexible, but with it comes complexity.

Note: I could have done the second layout using two panels and two `GridLayout`s as well - which is an important concept, you're not stuck to a single layout manager, you can use multiple panels, each using different layout managers and "compound" them together to produce a rich interface

Comment: Thank you, so if I wanted to let say build a calculator with positioning the buttons in specific areas, essentially transforming the entire panel into one big grid and plotting my containers inside that grid what would be the best layout to use and how would I do that. My initial thought was that this was the best layout. But now that I have seen what you have posted, it seems that this might not be the best choice. Thanks.

Comment: A lot depends on your ultimate goal, for example, if you only want all the buttons to be the same size and occupy the available space of the container evenly, then something like `GridLayout` might be a better choice, however, if you want to, like most calculator UIs, allow the `0` button to expand more space then the other buttons, then `GridBagLayout` is the direction you need to go

Answer (score -2):

If you're going to be doing much UI building, it would greatly benefit you to download the Netbeans IDE and learn to use its GUI builder. It's an excellent GUI builder, and the visual feedback you get as you tweak layout parameters is incredibly helpful for getting the hang of UI building, and especially for getting the hang of how the various `GridBagLayout` parameters work. It's much more efficient for experimentation than a "write-run-tweak-rerun" loop.

Manually writing UI code is my least favorite thing. Don't inflict it on yourself if possible!